# What should I point to my webhost when requesting for Subversion support?

Tags: svn, web-hosting, repository

There's this webhost SP which I liked a lot that said to me that they could add support for Subversion if I wanted. They just asked me to send an e-mail with everything I wanted and how I want it to work and such.

The only things I can remember is that I need support for Subversion and unlimited repositories.

What other details you guys think it's important I point out for a proper Subversion support?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust my source control on an infrastructure where the admins had to ask *me* how to set it up :)

Comment: They didn't ask me how to set it up, they are asking me my requirements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- accessing the repository via https, not just http (so your authentication data is encrypted)
- easy way to add new users (web interface)
- daily backups of the repository
- be able to add files to the repository folder to install hook scripts (in case you need one)

not really SVN only, but I would also ask to set up an issue tracker and integrate it with svn (e.g., Trac is usually used for this kind of setup).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I knew that I was forgetting something important like https :P

Answer (score 1):

Your webhost SP may be tempted to create an image of an empty repository setup once, and then clone that whenever a new repository is required. This will result in repositories with the same UUID and can cause problems, e.g. with [TortoiseSVN's log caching](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-logcache). The UUID must be unique.

To avoid this, make sure the repository is created (with `svnadmin create`) rather than cloned, or alternatively change the cloned UUID with  `svnadmin setuuid`.

Comment: If me (the users) have access to create their own repos without requesting the SP to create them, I believe that will not be a issue?

Comment: Then your requirement is simple: root access to your own virtual machine server, and then you can set up everything yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to ask your webhost SP to provide a **commit mailing list** for each repository.

Comment: Not really interested in that but thanks for the suggestion.